# Correct format pattern for string to DateTime

Tags: php, datetime

I have a string looking like this `2016-11-29T14:04:07+00:00`, can anyone hint me what would be the correct format to in order to create a `DateTime` object using `createFromFormat` I have already tried some options but none of them seem to work until now.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If you want to save the datetie into mysql db, it would be - `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime` has predefined constants for certain formats. Your date follows the ISO 8601 standard and its equivalent `DateTime` constant is called `ATOM`. So try:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ATOM, '2016-11-29T14:04:07+00:00');
```

Note that there is another constant called `ISO8601` which is **not** compatible as stated in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.iso8601):

> This format is not compatible with ISO-8601, but is left this way for backward compatibility reasons. Use DateTime::ATOM or DATE_ATOM for compatibility with ISO-8601 instead.

Answer (score 1):

The correct format would be "c", the ISO 8601 date-format :)